# MySQL only returns a single row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table in my database which currently contains 2 records. The data is exactly the same in each record, except for a unique id and uploaded_date.

I am running a simply query to find data in the table, however, it is only returning one of the rows.

The data is as follows:

```
id    from_user    to_user    filename        uploaded_date
1     ABC123       XYZ123     filename1.pdf   2015-03-18 14:28:32
2     ABC123       XYZ123     filename.pdf    2015-03-18 14:52:19
```

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`file_uploads`) 
WHERE `from_user` = 'ABC123' 
  AND `to_user` = 'XYZ123' 
  AND `folder_path` = './uploads/ABC123' 
  AND `is_deleted` = 0 
  AND `to_user_archived` = 0 
ORDER BY `upload_date` DESC
```

Is this something that is built into MySQL as it thinks the rows are duplicates?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have `ORDER BY upload_date` - yet the column is called `uploaded_date`

Comment: No there is nothing built-in to eliminate the duplicate records for the above query, its the condition which returns one row. Better would be post some data and desired result.

Comment: we can't see the `folder_path` column. maybe it doesn't have same content for both rows? (neither `is_deleted`, nor `to_user_archived`)

Comment: You have columns in your selection criteria that dont exist in your example of your table. Please make sure that your example code MAKES SENSE

Comment: Verify that you don't have unexpected non-printing characters in string values.

Comment: Let's all get into a *group guess*. ^ (No hugging today).

Comment: Apologies, the uploaded_date is just a typo; it is upload_date.

Comment: folder_path, is_deleted and to_user_archived were excluded to save space. is_deleted contains either a 1 or 0 as does to_user_archived. folder_path contains a string which is the same on each row "./uploads/ABC123"

Comment: you should include all fields otherwise we cannot understand what you missed

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
SELECT * FROM `file_uploads`
WHERE `from_user` = 'ABC123' 
AND `to_user` = 'XYZ123' 
AND `filename` = 'filename1.pdf'
ORDER BY `uploaded_date` DESC
```